# Summernote in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-summernote (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-summernote).

When it is installed, I declare and add Ng2Summernote in `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { Ng2Summernote } from 'ng2-summernote/ng2-summernote';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Ng2Summernote
  ],
})
```

But I run `ng serve` => error:  "Unexpected value 'Ng2Summernote' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation".

I am using @angular/common": "^6.0.3 -- it failed, but it runs using angular 2.3.1.

Comment: I edited the question to re-format it and make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the [latest Version of Summernote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-summernote/v/1.12.0) only supports Angular 2. It was released more than one year ago.

With Angular 6 there are so many changes in code syntax applied that you won't succeed to get it running I guess.